# How can I get nth table column value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How can I get nth table column value? Ie. I would like to get 2nd column value.
The first one I get in this way - it works fine, but the nth(2) does not work:

```
$('body').on('click', '.confirmation1', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var produktNazwa = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").first().html();
    var produktWaga = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").nth(2).html();
    console.log(produktNazwa, produktWaga);
});
```

Any hints on this please? Thanks.

Comment: there is no function called `nth` in jQuery. You probably want [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `.nth()` in jQuery. Instead you can try with [**`.eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified *index*.

```
var produktWaga = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(2).html();
```

**OR:** You can include [**`:eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) as part of the selector:

```
var produktWaga = $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(2)").html();
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't recall having `nth` function in jQuery. I might be mistaken, but not that I know of. What you probably want is `eq()`

```
var produktWaga = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(2).html();
```